# Slow GUI in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware workstation 15 on Windows 10 with installed Fedora 28. My laptop is Surface Book with performance base. I allow the VM to use 2 cores of the processor, 8 GB of RAM and 2 GB of video memory. VMware tools are installed. What I see after is that the GUI is slow. For example, when typing the text (in the terminal) the latter appears on the screen after half of the second of typing

Is there any way to remove this problem?

Comment: How much RAM do you have total, 16GB?  Why do you need 2GB of video memory?  Reduce it to what's recommended. Over assigning resources to a VM generally hurts performance instead of increasing it.

Comment: @essjae : to what amount of video memory should I reduce?

Comment: I run my Linux VMs with the recommend value, 768MB.  Have had no performance issues with the GUI.

Comment: @essjae : what display resolution do you have in your virtual machine?

Comment: 2354x1298, in windowed mode.